# Issue fitting curves:

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I´m trying to fit my data to a certain function by when I try to plot it, I always get double lines as shown in the figure below. This is the code I´m using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import warnings

from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution


# bounds on parameters are set in generate_Initial_Parameters() below
def func_original(x,a,b,c):
   return a/(x**2)+b/x+c


# bounds on parameters are set in generate_Initial_Parameters() below
def func_recommended(x,a,b,c):
    return 1/(a*x**2+b*x+c)

# select peak function here
#func = func_original
func = func_recommended


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
# bounds on parameters are set in generate_Initial_Parameters() below
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    return np.sum((yData - func(xData, *parameterTuple)) ** 2)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # data min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    minSearch = min([minX, minY])
    maxSearch = max([maxX, maxY])

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minSearch, maxSearch]) # parameter bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minSearch, maxSearch]) # parameter bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([minSearch, maxSearch]) # parameter bounds for c
    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# load data from text file
data=np.loadtxt('gammaoh.txt')
use=np.transpose(data)

yData=use[0]
xData=use[2]


# generate initial parameter values
initialParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# curve fit the data
fittedParameters, niepewnosci = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

# create values for display of fitted peak function
a, b, c = fittedParameters
y_fit = func(xData, a, b, c)

plt.plot(xData, yData, 'bo', label='Puntos experimentais $\gamma_{OH}$', markersize=5) 
plt.plot(xData, (1/(xData**2*0.5998-2.29255*xData+1.7988)) , 'b-',label='Axuste $\gamma_{OH}$') 
plt.title('Axustes coeficientes de actividade ')
plt.xlabel('$\chi_{H_2O}$  ')
plt.ylabel('$\gamma$')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc=2)


plt.savefig('gammaoh.png')
```

[image: Plot of the data and the fit]

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how to fix this, thank you in advance. Also, if anyone knows a better way of fitting data to a given function, it would be nice if you could tell me.

Comment: Does perhaps the point (0.74,2.4) or something close to it come at the beginning of the data file?

Comment: The link to the text file is the following: [link](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmYcBNaWzapshDOb90fz3NHrKtgd)

Answer (score 2):

I have no deeper knowledge of the problem you are solving, but to avoid the extra line in the plot, it works if the lists are sorted according to x. I did this:

```
xData.sort()

tt = (1/(xData**2*0.5998-2.29255*xData+1.7988))

plt.plot(xData, tt , 'b-',label='Axuste $\gamma_{OH}$')
```

Comment: No need to sort inside the loop. You can also avoid much of the complicated logic by simply computing `tt` after sorting `xData`.